# Add line automatically

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA and I have the code below to automatically add a line when there is some content in a cell in column B. However, I'd like to modify the formula so that if I change the content within a cell that already had content in it or delete the content in a cell and rewrite something within the same cell later it doesnt add an extra line.
Many thanks!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'Test if change is in column B and only one cell changed
If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Columns("B")) Is Nothing And _
        Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then

    If len(Target)>0 then
          Target.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown      'Insert row below data entry
         'Target.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown       'Insert row above data entry
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there is not an event for `BeforeEdit` for a `Worksheet` (or a `Workbook`). What this means is that if you want to determine if cells in your target range have their contents "changed", it means you have to keep a record of what did is held in each cell, then compare the "change" in the cell to the previous content. This is not uncommon, but usually involves using a (hidden) worksheet to hold all the "current" values, then in the `Worksheet_Change` event, you make the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are inserting a row below to neaten up the document and make it easier to read the data (a blank row, that will always remain blank), then you could add a simple logic check using CountA before inserting the line to see whether there is already a blank row below the target cell. If there is a blank row it won't add one, if there isn't then it will add one:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'Test if change is in column B and only one cell changed
If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Columns("B")) Is Nothing And _
        Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then

    If Len(Target) > 0 And Application.CountA(Rows(Target.Offset(1).Row)) <> 0 Then 'New condition added here
          Target.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown      'Insert row below data entry
         'Target.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown       'Insert row above data entry
    End If
End If

End Sub
```